# Laravel API with AngularJS not working

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I am a newbie in Laravel and Angularjs. I follow up the article [How to Consume Laravel API with AngularJS](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-consume-laravel-api-with-angularjs/) step by step. 
After I finished the signup function(including signup.html, controller.js and service.js), I click the signup button for signup. But the button response nothing. I've test the back-end by postman just as [How to Build an API-Only JWT-Powered Laravel App](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-an-api-only-jwt-powered-laravel-app/?utm_source=sitepoint&utm_medium=relatedinline&utm_term=&utm_campaign=relatedauthor), and it works. I have no idea what's going on, what should I do first?

Here are the codes:

**signup.html:**

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
      <h2>Signup</h2>
        <p>Welcome! If you want to sign up to our awesome service, fill this form and press on "Signup"!</p>

        <hr>

        <p><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name..." ng-model="name" required /></p>
        <p><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address..." ng-model="email" required /></p>
        <p><input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password..." ng-model="password" required /></p>

        <hr>

        <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-success form-control" ng-click="signup()">Signup</button></p>

        <hr>

        <p><a href="#login">Already signed up? <b>Log in!</b></a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**js/controllers.js**

```
     bookWishlistAppControllers.controller('SignupController', ['$scope',      '$location', 'userService', function ($scope, $location, userService) {

        $scope.signup = function() {
            userService.signup(
                $scope.name, $scope.email, $scope.password,
                function(response){
                    alert('Great! You are now signed in! Welcome, ' + $scope.name + '!');
                $location.path('/');
            },
            function(response){
                alert('Something went wrong with the signup process. Try again later.');
            }
        );
    }

    $scope.name = '';
    $scope.email = '';
    $scope.password = '';

    if(userService.checkIfLoggedIn())
        $location.path('/');

}]);
```

**js/services.js**

```
var bookWishlistAppServices = angular.module('bookWishlistAppServices', [
'LocalStorageModule'
]);

bookWishlistAppServices.factory('userService', ['$http', 'localStorageService', function($http, localStorageService) {

    function checkIfLoggedIn() {

        if(localStorageService.get('token'))
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

    function signup(name, email, password, onSuccess, onError) {

        $http.post('/api/auth/signup', 
        {
            name: name,
            email: email,
            password: password
        }).
        then(function(response) {

            localStorageService.set('token', response.data.token);
            onSuccess(response);

        }, function(response) {

            onError(response);

        });

    }

    function login(email, password, onSuccess, onError){

        $http.post('/api/auth/login', 
        {
            email: email,
            password: password
        }).
        then(function(response) {

            localStorageService.set('token', response.data.token);
            onSuccess(response);

        }, function(response) {

            onError(response);

            });

    }

    function logout(){

        localStorageService.remove('token');

    }

    function getCurrentToken(){
        return localStorageService.get('token');
    }

    return {
        checkIfLoggedIn: checkIfLoggedIn,
        signup: signup,
        login: login,
        logout: logout,
        getCurrentToken: getCurrentToken
    }

}]);
```

**api_routes.php:**

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->version('v1', function ($api) {

    $api->post('auth/login', 'App\Api\V1\Controllers\AuthController@login');
    $api->post('auth/signup', 'App\Api\V1\Controllers\AuthController@signup');
    $api->post('auth/recovery', 'App\Api\V1\Controllers\AuthController@recovery');
    $api->post('auth/reset', 'App\Api\V1\Controllers\AuthController@reset');

    $api->group(['middleware' => 'api.auth'], function ($api) {
        $api->resource('books', 'App\Api\V1\Controllers\BookController');
    });
});
```

**AuthController.php:**

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{

    public function signup(Request $request)
    {
        $signupFields = Config::get('boilerplate.signup_fields');
        $hasToReleaseToken = Config::get('boilerplate.signup_token_release');

        $userData = $request->only($signupFields);

        $validator = Validator::make($userData, Config::get('boilerplate.signup_fields_rules'));

        if($validator->fails()) {
            throw new ValidationHttpException($validator->errors()->all());
        }

        User::unguard();
        $user = User::create($userData);
        User::reguard();

        if(!$user->id) {
            return $this->response->error('could_not_create_user', 500);
        }

        if($hasToReleaseToken) {
            return $this->login($request);
        }

        return $this->response->created();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if the route is working, and your backend service route is correct

Comment: The signup's route in services.js is: post:'/api/auth/login' . I think it match **AuthController.php** and **api_routes.php**....right?

Comment: The Angular Controller and Service look okay to me. And the index page is simply, it's a click and not a form submission. One thing though -- the middleware in your routes is extra and the URLs for the requests don't match up exactly, POST to /api/auth... with the group setup. For debugging, could you try setting up a simpler POST route in Laravel (like POST /api/auth/sign up) and then map that route to AuthCtrl@signup outside of the API block? Then we could tell if your routes and POST work in isolation from your API.